# How to control LEDs via a LDR and a button as well?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I'm currently working on a Node-RED webapplication to control several leds with switch buttons. Next, using a Python script to read the LDR value. This value will be used to determine if it's light or dark outside. When it's dark, one led has to be enabled and the others disabled, the opposite when it's light.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import cgitb ; cgitb.enable() 
import spidev 
import time 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)

spi = spidev.SpiDev() # create spi object
spi.open(0,0) # open spi port 0, device CS0 pin 24

# read SPI data 8 possible adc's (0 thru 7) 
def readadc(adcnum): 
 if ((adcnum > 7) or (adcnum < 0)): 
    return -1 
 r = spi.xfer2([1,(8+adcnum)<<4,0]) 
 adcout = ((r[1]&3) << 8) + r[2] 
 return adcout
```

As you can see, the rest of this script keeps going because of the while loop.

```
while True:
    tmp0 = readadc(0) # read channel 0 
    if(tmp0 > 500):
        msg = "LIGHT"
        GPIO.output(17, False)
    else:
        msg = "DARK"
        GPIO.output(17, True)
        GPIO.output(18, False)
        GPIO.output(22, False)
        GPIO.output(27, False)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print msg
```

Finnally, I can't use both. Once I click one a switch the led will go on for 1 second. I need to find a manner to combine both methods. Any tips?

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) what exactly isn't working?  You want to `combine both methods`...what does this mean?  Maybe you could elaborate a bit more (or be more specific).

Comment: So, this project consists out of two parts. First, I use 4 switches to control 4 leds via Node RED. Secondly, I use a while loop. This while loop will be used to send real time data about the currect light conditions. 

It's dark? then the first led enables and the other will disable.
It's light? All the leds will be disabled.

Now, Because of the while loop, I can't enable the leds with the switches anymore.

Comment: So, who "wins" out of the switches vs. the current conditions??  What do you want to happen when the light conditions indicate one thing, and the switch indicates another?

Comment: Then the switch has to change to the status of the current conditions, but I still want to be able to control the leds via the switches.

Comment: I am trying to exactly the same. But I am not able to find LDR plugin for node-red. Can you tell me how to install it so that I can get output from LDR?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF** what you want, is for the light conditions to dictate the initial led state, as well as updating the state when the light conditions change; but the switches to over-ride these until the light conditions change, then this should help:

```
light_set = None
while True:
    tmp0 = readadc(0) # read channel 0 
    if(tmp0 > 500) and light_set != "LIGHT":
        msg = "LIGHT"
        light_set = msg
        GPIO.output(17, False)
    else if light_set != "DARK":
        msg = "DARK"
        light_set = msg
        GPIO.output(17, True)
        GPIO.output(18, False)
        GPIO.output(22, False)
        GPIO.output(27, False)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print msg
```

This should "remember" what this code section last set the led to, so it won't keep setting it if it's changed with a switch.  It will still change it, when the current light conditions aren't what it last set it to though.

Comment: Thanks Gerrat, I only had to change the "else if" statement to 

`"elif light_set != "DARK" and tmp0 < 500):`

Otherwise the led would have been flickering when it's light